# Logback TimeBasedRollingPolicy with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, slf4j, spring-logback

I wrote a TimeBasedRollingPolicy *logback.xml*, and while the log file is created succesfully, it seems to be reading it from the *application.properties* instead. Here is my setup:

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>

    <appender name="ROLLING-FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING-FILE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

**application.properties**

```
logging.path=/path/to/log/folder/
logging.file=${logging.path}myLog
logging.pattern.file=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

When I run my application, the log is successfully saved in the correct path, but only as *myLog*. I would want it to be appended with the date (as in the logback.xml). Note I do want to keep taking the *logging.path* and *logging.file* from the *application.properties* because I have multiple depending on the environment.

Thanks

Comment: here some examples https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/4497/configuring-logback-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to set a `logging.file` or `logging.path` property, not both.
So `logging.file=/path/to/log/folder/myLog` should be enough to get a `myLog` log file in the specified path.

[The spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output) mentions that.

2) This is the format pattern for the log **rolling**, not for the **current** log :

```
 <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
```

You get this format automatically for the current log file when it is rolled/archived because the time limit defined by the pattern is reached. In your case, it means everyday.

Comment: thanks, though one little clarification, given my logback.xml, I had to set logging.file in the application.properties and not logging.path, because the logback file references LOG_FILE.

Comment: @Tiberiu Sure. It was a mistake from mine. Thanks for precising it. I updated to makes it clearer.